# How to return to bookmarked hash-bang URLs within a single page application?

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application, html5-history, hashbang

I understand the HTML5 History API and how it enables to back and forward buttons within a single page application (SPA).

But given the URL displayed by the API, how can I return to application state when given the faux URL via a bookmark or emailed URL?  For instance...

If my SPA loads from http://dacracot.org/myApp, the user may navigate around until the URL as morphed to http://dacracot.org/myApp#!ec2f209f25e11.  The user decide they want this to be their start point within the SPA from now on and bookmarks it.  Furthermore, they think it is a good start point for their coworkers and email the URL to them.

So when my SPA loads, I can trap the hash-bang marker #!ec2f209f25e11, but now what?  What mechanism do I have available that puts them at the same click stream that they expect?  Do I have to create a route table with every display option?  This (I hope) is not my only option.

Comment: What did you do the first time the user navigated to that hash/URL? Do the same thing now ...

Comment: Hashbangs were what people used before pushState and friends existed. I don't understand why you would mix them.

Comment: @Quentin pushState is temporal and does not help for stored URLs.

Comment: @dacracot — I have no idea what you are trying to say with that sentence.

Comment: You say that as if it actually meant anything ...

Comment: @CBroe The click stream to get to a given point in the SPA is complex.  How would I know what that state is?

Comment: @dacracot — The URL should tell you what that state is. That's the point of URLs. (The specific set of clicks followed to get to that state should not be important).

Comment: Well if you have no proper association between state and URL yet, then that is the first thing you need to get done.

Comment: @Quentin "pushState is temporal and does not help for stored URLs"... In other words... Copy a URL, quit your browser, start your browser, paste the URL.  The previous state was lost from history api perspective since the browser restarted and the #tag must be dealt with via the SPA.  Or so I believe.

Comment: @dacracot — If you were using the history API properly, then it wouldn't include hashbangs, and the server could provide the page in the desired state. Hashbangs are a dirty hack from before we had the history API which depend on client side JS to restore the state.

Comment: @Quentin "which depends on client side JS to restore the state"... That statement is key.

Comment: @dacracot — You attributed the problem to pushState, but pushState doesn't have that problem. Hashbangs do.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to create a route table with every display option?

More or less.

Since the fragment identifier is only available on the client, you need client-side logic that can use the URL to determine the state that the page should be in when the user asks to load it.

Comment: If true, then I need a #tag from every potential display state in my SPA and a routing table to execute it upon return.  Bummer.